# Apparemment / probablement / sûrement, ils ne s’attendaient pas à nous voir ici

Tags: adverbes

> **Apparemment**, ils ne s’attendaient pas à nous voir ici, à notre
> désobéissance.
>
> **Probablement**, ils ne s’attendaient pas à nous voir ici, à notre
> désobéissance.
>
> **Sûrement**, ils ne s’attendaient pas à nous voir ici, à notre
> désobéissance.

Plusieurs personnes m'ont dit que je ne pouvais pas mettre *probablement* en début de phrase. Est-ce aussi le cas d'*apparemment* et de *sûrement* ?

Comment: Probablement pas ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Mais pourquoi ? Quelle est la différence entre _apparemment_ et _probablement_ placés en début de phrase ?

Comment: Ma réponse était un clin d'œil car c'était justement une phrase qui commençait par *probablement*. Je vais faire une vraie réponse.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'existe pas de règle qui interdise de mettre *probablement* en début de phrase. C'est rarement fait car quand c'est le cas, *probablement* est souvent une réponse à une question ou une supposition qui précède.

> Tu arriveras en retard ?
> Probablement, j'ai beaucoup de travail à terminer.

*Apparemment* et *sûrement* peuvent aussi être des réactions à ce qui vient d'être dit, mais sont plus souvent des adverbes qui s'appliquent à ce qui est dit juste après.

> Apparemment, il n'a pas bien appris sa leçon.

> Sûrement, il fait son chemin.

Comment: _car c'était justement une phrase_ --- je l'ai compris // Est-ce que _Probablement, il n'a pas bien appris sa leçon_ est possible aussi ? Peut-il s'appliquer à la suite de la phrase ?

Comment: Oui, mais si tu tiens à commencer par *probablement*, tu pourrais d'écrire le plus soutenu: *Probablement n'a-t-il pas bien appris sa leçon.* La forme la plus courante serait *Il n'a probablement pas bien appris sa leçon*.

Comment: Merci, je sais que la manière la plus standard serait _Probablement n'a-t-il pas bien appris sa leçon_ mais j'aimerais aussi pouvoir mettre _probablement_ au début, c'est juste que je me demandais : c'est sous l'influence du russe que j'ai la tendance à le placer au début ou ce serait quand même correct aussi en français.

Comment: Une autre façon d'indiquer que le *probablement* s'applique au reste de la phrase est d'utiliser *que* plutôt qu'une virgule : ***Probablement qu'il n'a pas bien appris sa leçon***.

Comment: Oui, mais pourquoi "probablement que..." et "Probablement n'a-t-il pas..." seraient-ils préférables au "probablement" + virgule ?... D'autant plus que "apparemment" + virgule est possible.

Comment: Les deux premiers ne sont pas ambigus.